# fx:script for AS3 and MXML for?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I find the flexibility in using fx:script to get all AS3 see each other easily but I have a few MXML module, some actionscript from main.mxml want to access the ID in specific module such as module1.mxml. How do I get it to work?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate question, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289314/access-mxml-component-from-external-actionscipt-file

Comment: I have *no* idea what you're asking.  Can you make this more coherent?

Comment: I'm with @J_A_X on this one.  You should consider rewording your question to a bit more clear.  Do you want to access a variable that exists inside a separately compiled MX Module?

Comment: ok papachan, I guess this was the only way to get it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a module1.mxml is a defined component in main.mxml, you can give it an ID and reference public variables and functions inside of it.  The following shorthand code demonstrates this.

```
<mx:Application creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler()">
  <fx:Script>
     function creationCompleteHandler() : void
     {
        m1.initializeModule();
     }

  </fx:Script>
  <module1 id="m1" />
</mx:Application>
```